# How to extract only the navbar code in this template

Tags: html

I am using a template for my website and I want to extract only the nav bar code from it so that I can do the extended code to make it apply for other pages too. I hope someone can help me. I am really sorry for pasting the entire file but I do not want to miss any crucial codes. I have also tried other ways at the bottom I have written a way on how I have tried but nothing seems to work.

home.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Everything In One Blog!!!</title>


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.css' %}">

<!-- MAIN CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/tooplate-style.css' %}">

</head>
<body>

<!-- PRE LOADER -->
<div class="preloader">
     <div class="spinner">
          <span class="sk-inner-circle"></span>
     </div>
</div>


<!-- MENU -->
<div class="navbar custom-navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">

          <!-- NAVBAR HEADER -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
               <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <!-- lOGO -->
               <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand">Everything In One Blog!!</a>
          </div>

          <!-- MENU LINKS -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'post' %}" class="smoothScroll">Posts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">Studio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">Our People</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Let's talk</a></li>
               </ul>
          </div>

     </div>
</div>


<!-- HOME -->
<section id="home" class="parallax-section">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="home-text">
                         <h1>Your Website has a video background!</h1>
                         <p>Feel free to download and use HTML templates from Tooplate</p>
                         <ul class="section-btn">
                              <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll"><span data-hover="Discover More">Discover More</span></a>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Video -->
     <video controls autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="{% static 'videos/video.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
</section>


<!-- ABOUT -->
<section id="about" class="parallax-section">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="about-info">
                         <h3>Introducing Scenic</h3>
                         <h1>This template is designed for you. Sed ornare, tortor nec placerat lacinia, leo quam rutrum leo, eget posuere ipsum sem eu justo. Integer nunc libero.</h1>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- PROJECT -->
<section id="project" class="parallax-section">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">


               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <!-- PROJECT ITEM -->
                    <div class="project-item">
                         <a href="{% static 'images/project-image1.jpg' %}" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="{% static 'images/project-image1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">

                              <div class="project-overlay">
                                   <div class="project-info">
                                        <h1>Large Sea Wave</h1>
                                        <h3>Nam feugiat dui in nisi</h3>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <!-- PROJECT ITEM -->
                    <div class="project-item">
                         <a href="{% static 'images/project-image2.jpg' %}" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="{% static 'images/project-image2.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">

                              <div class="project-overlay">
                                   <div class="project-info">
                                        <h1>Large Sea Wave</h1>
                                        <h3>Nam feugiat dui in nisi</h3>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <!-- PROJECT ITEM -->
                    <div class="project-item">
                         <a href="{% static 'images/project-image3.jpg' %}" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="{% static 'images/project-image3.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">

                              <div class="project-overlay">
                                   <div class="project-info">
                                        <h1>Large Sea Wave</h1>
                                        <h3>Nam feugiat dui in nisi</h3>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <!-- PROJECT ITEM -->
                    <div class="project-item">
                         <a href="{% static 'images/project-image4.jpg' %}" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="{% static 'images/project-image4.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">

                              <div class="project-overlay">
                                   <div class="project-info">
                                        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
                                        <h3>Mollis aliquam faucibus urna</h3>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>               

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- TEAM -->
<section id="team" class="parallax-section">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <!-- SECTION TITLE -->
                    <div class="section-title">
                         <h1>Meet Our People</h1>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="clearfix"></div>

               <div id="owl-team" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item">
                         <div class="team-item">
                              <img src="{% static 'images/team-image1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <div class="team-overlay">
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                         <p>Catherine Jann</p>
                         <h3>Head Designer</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item">
                         <div class="team-item">
                              <img src="{% static 'images/team-image2.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <div class="team-overlay">
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-github"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                         <p>Luke Wara</p>
                         <h3>Speciality Focus</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item">
                         <div class="team-item">
                              <img src="{% static 'images/team-image3.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <div class="team-overlay">
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-dribbble"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-behance"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                         <p>Mono Mana</p>
                         <h3>Art director</h3>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item">
                         <div class="team-item">
                              <img src="{% static 'images/team-image1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <div class="team-overlay">
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                         <p>Cherry Lynn</p>
                         <h3>Marketing Manager</h3>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>





<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Digital Studio</h2>
                    <p>321 Donec et justo id risus, Malesuada pharetra,<br> Tristique vestibulum,<br> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>


               </div>



               <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">

                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                    <p>Sed vestibulum posuere ante, eget blandit metus. Morbi sodales feugiat erat, et placerat sapien suscipit ut.</p>
                    <ul class="social-icon">
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>

               </div>

               <div class="clearfix"></div>

               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="copyright-text">
                         <p>Copyright © 2018 Company Name 

                         | Design: Tooplate</p>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</footer>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.parallax.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/magnific-popup-options.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/modernizr.custom.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/smoothscroll.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

base.html/ How I have tried to solve(And miserably fail to do so):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.css' %}">

<!-- MAIN CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/tooplate-style.css' %}">
<!-- Included css files -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MENU -->
<div class="navbar custom-navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">

          <!-- NAVBAR HEADER -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
               <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <!-- lOGO -->
               <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand">Everything In One Blog!!</a>
          </div>

          <!-- MENU LINKS -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'post' %}" class="smoothScroll">Posts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">Studio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">Our People</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Let's talk</a></li>
               </ul>
          </div>

     </div>
</div>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.parallax.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/magnific-popup-options.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/modernizr.custom.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/smoothscroll.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the navbar of your page.
I have included `boostrap.min.css` and `fontawesome.min.css` which are publicly available. As you can see in this example, that is not enough.

```html
<!-- Included css files -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MENU -->
<div class="navbar custom-navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">

          <!-- NAVBAR HEADER -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
               <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <!-- lOGO -->
               <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand">Everything In One Blog!!</a>
          </div>

          <!-- MENU LINKS -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'post' %}" class="smoothScroll">Posts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">Studio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">Our People</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Let's talk</a></li>
               </ul>
          </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

What you need is also the CSS.
If there is any JavaScript related to these elements, you also need that.

Looking at the code here, these are the classes you need from their source .css files:

```
class="navbar custom-navbar navbar-fixed-top"
class="container"
class="navbar-header"
class="navbar-toggle"
class="icon icon-bar"
class="navbar-brand"
class="collapse navbar-collapse"
class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"
class="smoothScroll"
```

These are the other css files linked in `<head>` where you need to look for these classes:

```
magnific-popup.css
owl.theme.css
owl.carousel.css
tooplate-style.css
```

Comment: What you need is the `html`, the `css` and the `js`. It is going to work when you figure out how to collect it.

Comment: I know, that is why I pasted every css file link file and js link file into the navbar area but does not seem to work it shows the exact same thing when you run this snippet.

Comment: Paste your new code and change the question.

Comment: Yes I have pasted.